# How to add dictionary value to a list in a loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to add value values from dictionary to list with for loop. However, I couldn't. I will be glad if you help. thanks

The operations I want to do;
I want to append Key: mb Value: 3, named 3 to Number_of_Matches list.
I want to append Key: edh Value: 02:00, 02:00 to the list named Hour with append.
Key: ede Value: Thursday, January 20th, I want to append the data named Date to the list named Date.

[Dictionary values that I want to import into lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npGg1.png)

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'sportprogram.iddaa.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'client-transaction-id': 'bbf42875-d605-4efa-93e6-a4ec5efc6d4d',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'timestamp': '1642628001345',
    'platform': 'web',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'origin': 'https://www.iddaa.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.iddaa.com/',
    'accept-language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

params = (
    ('ProgramType', '1'),
    ('SportId', '1'),
    ('MukList', '1_1,2_88,2_100,2_101_2.5,2_89'),
)

response = requests.get('https://sportprogram.iddaa.com/SportProgram', headers=headers, params=params)

result_json = response.json()

Number_of_Matches = []
Hour = []
Date = []
League = []
Team = []
for i in result_json['data']['spg']:
    for j in i['eventGroup'][0]['eventResponse']:
        for k,l in j.items():
            print("Key:",k," Value:",l) # I Couldn't Do Any More
```

Comment: Please [don't add data as an image, but include the text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question); also, it would be better to provide a sample of the original json being processed instead of some output of a script printing part of it. Are you literally asking how to create a dictionary? You already have they keys and values, and you know which ones you want. So what more to do than `if key in ['a', 'b', 'c']: d[key] = value`?

Comment: I want to add the dictionary values in the for loop to the empty lists. For example, I want to add values such as date and time to these lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing, use `dict.get` method to get the values of the keys you want and append to the relevant lists:

```
Number_of_Matches = []
Hour = []
Date = []
for i in result_json['data']['spg']:
    for j in i['eventGroup'][0]['eventResponse']:
        Number_of_Matches.append(j.get('mb'))
        Hour.append(j.get('edh'))
        Date.append(j.get('ede'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish happiness to your family and loved ones.

Comment: @AbdurrahmanAY did it work?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for much